# Docker not found inside container instead of passed daemon as a volume

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Can anybody help me? This docker-compose file worked for me a few days ago with docker command available inside the container, but now it throws: `docker: not found` inside.

The docker daemon on the host is on `/usr/local/bin/docker`. It's a mac.

Any idea? Could you help me to try this on yours guys? Thks

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins
    build:
      context: jenkins
    # entrypoint: /var/jenkins_home/entrypoint
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxx
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxx
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: centos
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock      
    networks:
      - net
  db_host:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
    networks:
      - net
networks:
    net:
```

`Dockerfile` for `remote_host` service is the following:

```
RUN yum install -y openssh-server

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "1234" | passwd remote_user --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen > /dev/null 2>&1

RUN yum install -y mysql

RUN yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum install -y python-pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install awscli

# CMD /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen -D
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant Dockerfile (and in particular highlight where you install a `docker` binary there)? Since the containers run inside a Linux VM you can’t directly use the MacOS host `docker` (and also the `docker-compose.yml` file you show doesn’t attempt to mount it).

Comment: I added the `Dockerfile` for `remote_host`. Can you help me? A little bit lost with all this.